# Address query in include function

Tags: php, path, fragment, query-string, include-path

I want include a file such as header.php but by a query ex:

> include **DIR**."header.php?v=s";

But it not execute. And just perform by using include without "?v=s"...
Why?!

Comment: I think you need simple `include 'header.php'`, and use `$v = $_GET['v'] ?? '';` in `header.php`. Also i suggest to read about differences in `include`, `require`, `include_once` and `require_once`. And about `$_GET`, `$_POST` and whole `$_GLOBALS`.

Comment: And what is your question? I think you do it in wrong way. You can't pass $_GET as filename 'argument'. Include needs filepath. With parameters like your `?v=s` you should work in included file by $_GET.

Comment: I checked my codes in header.php again and i used >> if(isset($_GET["v"])&& $_GET["v"]=='s'): //code goes here endif; but an error throw in my page like this >>failed to open stream but when use it without query it work well.

Comment: And i also understood that you can add a false query in an address bar or in other functions such as header("location:header.php?gm=50") and  it work without error... even if you doesnt use any code in header.php.... but include or same codes is exception...Why?

Comment: can you show me your php files with pastebin.com?